# Migrating multi-level branch structure from SVN to GIT

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to completely migrate SVN repository to GIT. It has following file structure.

[image]

Same for tags. I tried following command.

git svn clone  --tags=tags/*/* --branches=branches/*/* --no-metadata

Above command is running for 3 days now. Repository size is not that big. So far I can see only .git folder of around 150MB size. Is it normal? or I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't (**must not**) use wildcards in tags/branches **roots** definitions
2. `--tags`|`--branches` [can be specified more than once](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) in options of `git svn clone`

If your *real branches* (tags) are directories under `branch_root_N` (`tag_root_N`) you have to add one additional `--branches=PATH/TO/branch_root_N` **for every root** of branches/tags of your repository